# how to scope multiple radio button sets

Tags: ractivejs

ref: [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpcsn0Lf/)

The html is:

```
<script id='radio' type='text/ractive'>
  <div>
    <input type='radio' name='{{status}}' value='true' />
    <input type='radio' name='{{status}}' value='false' />
    {{status}}
  </div>
</script>
<div id='container' />
```

and the javascript is:

```
Item = Ractive.extend({
  template : '#radio'
})

new Ractive({
  el : '#container',
  template : "{{#items:i}}<item status='{{status}}' />{{/items}}",
  components : { item : Item },
  data:{items :[{status : 'false'},{status : 'true'}]}
})
```

So there are two items each with a pair of radio buttons to set status to true or false.

Problem is that the 'name' attribute is the same for both items (i.e. in all four radio buttons). So the radio buttons don't behave as two pairs (one per item) but they behave instead as a group of four.

How can this be written such that each item has its own pair of true/false radio buttons?

Comment: Structure it in a way so you can give each pair a different name

Comment: how do you do that, Dave, when the items are rendered using the same template? I agree this is what needs to be done, but I haven't figured out how.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the [Ractive github issues](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1939#issuecomment-94998341).

As noted in the issue comment, scoping can be achieved by wrapping the radio buttons inside a  element. This will not work when adding the form element creates nested forms, but it will work in my case.